# How can I insert a blank line between each row when writing to a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv

Here is the contents of my input CSV file:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

Here is the output what I want:

```
A1

A2

A3

A4
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$content = Get-Content D:\test\final.csv 
ForEach ($line in $content) {write-Content "`n$line" Set-Content d:\test\q.csv }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did have is close to a solution. First issue being is I am not aware of a standard cmdlet called `write-content`. Changing very little in your code you could have updated it to this to get results.

```psh
$content = Get-Content D:\test\final.csv 
ForEach($line in $content){
    "`n$line" | Add-Content d:\test\q.csv
}
```

Use of `set-content`, the way you had it, would cause the file to be overwritten each time which you want to be appending. But we can improve on this and get the same results.

```
Get-Content D:\test\final.csv | ForEach-Object{"`n$_"} | Set-Content d:\test\q.csv
```

Comment: It worked . Thanks a lot Matt! I have been working on it for last 2 days. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @RajReddy Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer with the green check mark on the left. See you again later!

Answer (score 0):

How do you read the csv file?

If you are using the [Get-Content cmldet](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjArvbVl4rGAhXBnHIKHcxDCYA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fde-de%2Flibrary%2Fhh849787(v%3Dwps.620).aspx&ei=WtR6VcCZDcG5ygPMh6WACA&usg=AFQjCNGaRe4pFzwx7bbD23E_T0cXaETWDw&sig2=AIl5OJCC1o-hs89l8wUgww&bvm=bv.95515949,d.bGQ), you can use the [-split](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx) parameter for strings:

```powershell
(Get-Content -Path $Path) -split ' '
```

Comment: You misinterpreted the input due to improper formatting.